# Offset() incorrect in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I'm tried to put layer 1 override layer 2(when i drag layer 2) but Offset() incorrect. I use jQuery UI from Google

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[File from jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/f5tonyhall/ug0ey9q9/)

Comment: Added new tags, remove redundant words.

Comment: Well I can't drag anything on that fiddle demo ... make that work and we can see why offset is wrong

Comment: Thank you so much! my problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are assigning the top and left properties wrongly while setting the offset to the div.

`top` property should be assigned the value of variable `y` and `left` property with the variable `x`.

Change the code to below:

```
$('.show-div').offset({top: y, left: x });
```